# Fiiling missing values with average number by applying groupying function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, rolling-computation

I have a DataFrame with missing values and I am trying to clean the NANs without dropping them. Below is a snapshot of the DF.

I need to first sort the 'Date'columns and then group them by City names and then fill the NANs by the 7 days average number. This way, all the feature columns that contain NaNs will be filled by an average value of only that specific city with 7 days period.

| City | Date | FeatureA | FeatureB | FeatureC | FeatureD | FeatureE | FeatureF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City A | 2020-03-07 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 2 | NAN | 1 |
| City B | 2020-03-07 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 2 |
| City B | 2020-03-07 | NAN | NAN | NAN | NAN | NAN | 3 |
| City A | 2020-03-08 | NaN | 3 | 1 | NAN | 6 | NAN |

```
df['FeatureA'].fillna(df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['City'])['FeatureA'].rolling(window = 7, center = True).mean().astype(int), inplace=True)
```

I face the error of Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: (I think) It's not possible to fill NaN values of the first rows using a moving average because the first values of rolling are obviously null (not enough observations). In your case what do you want to do to fill NaN values of the 10 first dates for each city?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now, I realize why I am facing this error. Do you have any suggestions on how we could convert these rows to 0 so then the .astype(int) work. I was thinking after that I just filter does rows and edit them manually or drop them